# Get Facebook post in multiple languages using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localization

I am trying to make a script which will get a facebook post and post it to my wordpress blog, but my blog is translated into multiple languages. I'd like to take an advantage of multi-language posts on Facebook and get these posts using Graph API with their translations. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `locale` parameter:

```
/some-page/feed?locale=en_US

/some-page/feed?locale=de_DE
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

If there is no version of a post available in the requested locale, I think you should get the “original”, the language the post was originally written in, before other languages were added.